# Why menu Item is not selected after pressing it and open its page?

Tags: asp.net, menu

I wonder why About MenuItem is not selected (highlighted) after I pressed it!

This is the default template of ASP.Net web application. Is there something ready or I have to implement it by my self?

[image]

**CSS:**

```
/* TAB MENU   
----------------------------------------------------------*/
div.hideSkiplink
{
    background-color:#3a4f63;
    width:100%;
}

div.menu
{
    padding: 4px 0px 4px 8px;
}

div.menu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    border: 1px #4e667d solid;
    color: #dde4ec;
    display: block;
    line-height: 1.35em;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
    background-color: #465c71;
    color: #cfdbe6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be easy fixable by editing the css ? Can You post the css of those buttons here ?

Comment: I added the CSS, but I don't think it'll be done by CSS. I think it needs some code.

Comment: Thanks for the css, it seems fine ... Is the "home" menu item highlited, when You press it ?

Comment: @Jevgeni Bogatyrjov: No, and my whole question is "why it's not highlighted" "

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with this very item for some time and wondered why the vanilla ASP.NET solution did not support what we needed.  After some experimenting, I came up with this fix which involves changing two files in the vanilla solution:

1) modify the **Styles/Site.css** file to add a definition and modify another.
a) add this in the menu section:

```
div.menu ul li .selected
{
    background-color: #bfcbd6;
    color: #465c71;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

b) Remove the visited directive by changing this line:

```
div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
```

to this one:

```
div.menu ul li a
```

2) This will show the 'selected' menu item in a highlighted color.  However, the selected item is cleared somehow in the page callback sequence.  To get around this issue, I made this modification to the **Site.Master.cs** file, basically to select the tab which contains the URL that we are looking at:

```
private void HighlightSelectedMenuItem()
{
    string MyURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    foreach (MenuItem mi in NavigationMenu.Items)
    {
        string mytest = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(mi.NavigateUrl);
        if (MyURL.Contains(mytest))
        {
            mi.Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now just add this method to your Page_Load method and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a sitemap and sitemap datasource? To my knowledge you need those to get automatic insertion of the "selected" class in your list items.

After that you use the following css rule to style the selected menu item.

```
#mainmenu ul li a.selected {
  background-color: Yellow;
}
```